# How to solve the equation of $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{2205}$ in integers?

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations, radicals, integers

How to solve the equation of $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{2205}$ in integers?
How in general to solve the similar equations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple factorization yields $\sqrt{2205} = 21\sqrt{5} $
$$\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{2205}-\sqrt{y}$$
$$x=2205+y-2.21\sqrt{5}\sqrt{y}$$
$$42\sqrt{5y}=2205+y-x$$
$$y\text{   is in the form of } 5k^2$$
$$y=k\sqrt{5}\Rightarrow\sqrt{x}=l{5}$$

Then we have,

$\sqrt{x}=0,\sqrt{y}=21\sqrt{5}$

$\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{5},\sqrt{y}=20\sqrt{5}$ and so on...

For these type of problems, use the fact that $a+\sqrt{b}=c+\sqrt{d}$ where b,d are not perfect squares $\Rightarrow a=c \text{ and }  b=d$

Comment: oh I missed, $\sqrt{x}=l\sqrt{5}$

Comment: I don't understand you. If you mean the number of solutions, the answer is  YES.

Comment: sqrt(y)=ksqrt(5)?

Comment: right side of $42\sqrt{5y}=2205+y-x$ is some integer. Therefore left side too will be an integer. We have a problem with $\sqrt{5y}$. That too should be an integer. Therefore, $5y$ is a perfect square. $5y=a^2$ for some $a$. As left side is divisible by $5$, $a$ too should be divisible by $5$. Then $a$ can be written as $5k$. $a=5k\Rightarrow y=5k^2$. (which is a long way to get 5k^2. If you are bit experienced, you will able to straight forwardly say $y=5k^2)$